# LC Resonance circuit : output voltage

Tags: analog, resonance

What I understand(FACTS) :

In for example a LC resonance circuit the output can many times greater than the input voltage. 
At resonance the impedance of the inductor is the same as the impedance of the capacitor.

At the resonance frequence Xl=Xc

What I fail to understand

If the impedance's are equal, how can the output voltage be larger than the input voltage? 
Although not correct, you would almost start to reason that the output voltage is half the input voltage(voltage divider). 
Where the output voltage is the voltage across the capacitor.

It seems so counter intuitive.

Why is the voltage higher at the output? 
What is a intuitive way of explaining why the output voltage is higher than the input voltage.
Or is it one of those circuit where it only starts to make sense when you deriver the transfer function.
[image: source elprocus.com]

Comment: first, define where in your circuit your "output voltage" is being measured. Then *mathematically* (with an equation) define what you meant when you said "the impedances must be equal". Being exact here makes a difference!

Comment: The impedances aren't equal they are complex conjugates at resonance. Big difference

Comment: In the circuit you show, the voltage across C at resonance is not just large, it is infinite.  Or equivalently: without any R, the peak voltage across C will be higher on each cycle, ramping upwards without limit.

Comment: Actually XL=-XC at resonance for that circuit.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is the voltage higher at the output? What is a intuitive way of
>   explaining why the output voltage is higher than the input voltage. Or
>   is it one of those circuit where it only starts to make sense when you
>   drive the transfer function.

Inductors and capacitors store energy *over time*, this means that the voltage or current can get higher than the initial voltage or current:

[image]
Source: [libretext: 14.5: Oscillations in an LC Circuit](https://phys.libretexts.org/TextBooks_and_TextMaps/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Map%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics%2C_Electricity%2C_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/14%3A_Inductance/14.5%3A_Oscillations_in_an_LC_Circuit)

This only happens at the resonant point formed by the capacitor and inductor, the circuit wants to oscillate at a certain frequency (the Q point), and will do so. The energy in the system is preserved but you can get higher voltage.

This property of inductors is how a DC to DC converter works, we charge inductors to create a magnetic field, then switch them off which momentarily creates a higher voltage.

Comment: your answer shows the oscillation between the energy in the inductor and capacitor but does not give any insight of why the output voltage is higher than input voltage. The fact that energy is stored in the capacitor over time is a bit confusing w.r.t. the picture as it shows a oscillating energy.

Comment: @Navaro, calculate the output voltage at resonance using the voltage divider rule. What do you get?

Answer (score 2):

As a boy, I had a 'rocket radio'. No battery, just an alligator clip to attach to the heating vent. To tune it, I would pull the nose cone in and out. I often wondered how it made a sound I could hear (earphone only) with no battery.

Voltage Spike has provided the answer. But let's see what's going on. According to wiki, analog radio signals, by the time they reach your home, are in the order of picovolts. For my little radio to work, that had to be boosted somehow. Resonance provides the means to do that.

When a circuit resonates, it sends energy back and forth between the inductor and capacitor. If the resistance is sufficiently low, such a circuit can continue to oscillate even *after* the power source is removed. These circuits were called "ringing" circuits in the past, because like bells, they would continue to ring after they were 'struck'.

In my rocket radio, the input is the tiny radio signal. I adjusted the value of C by sliding the nose cone, which adjusted the resonant frequency. When I hit a radio station, the energy from that signal starts to fill both the capacitor and the inductor with energy. At resonance, you can think of that energy as sloshing back and forth between the inductor and the capacitor. When the inductor is 'full', the capacitor is empty, and vice-versa.

It is this *extra* charge that is the source of the amplification. Imagine you had two equal teams of big men playing tug of war, where first one pulls one way, and then the other team pulls them back. That is the reactive energy flowing across the resistor. By modulating the radio signal on that tug-of-war rope, you get the advantage of having all the force of the teams added to your signal. The voltage increases and becomes strong enough to activate my earphone.

Note: This does not violate conservation of energy. Like a transformer, it just changes the relative values of V and I. I'm sure my dinky earphone only needed a miniscule amount of current.

Comment: Welcome Kevin! And thanks for the story, that's pretty cool